# Classic ASP variable issue

Tags: asp-classic

I have a classic asp page that is inside of a iFrame.

In this page I have the following form code:

```
        <input type="hidden" id="xPar" name="xPar" value="<%=obj.Parameter1 %>" />
```

When I view this page, I would say 90% of the time the value in the form field changes.  However, there are times where the value just isn't right.

obj.Parameter1 is being returned from a COM object.  I've seen the COM object set this property, I've even seen other asp pages later on pass in the correct value.  However, on this code 10% of the time the value does not change from previous value.

i.e. -

- First time : e1
- Second time : e2
- Third time : e2
- Fourth time : e4

It doesn't always happen in the 2nd and 3rd time, that was just an example of what I'm seeing.

I'm not sure what is happening.  It almost looks like the variable is being cached.  Does anyone have any suggestions on what I might be missing?

Comment: Without knowing the logic in the rest of your code, or the code in the COM object, it's going to be very hard to tell you the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like IE cache problems (assuming IE as it has the most problems with cache - personal experience) so just append unique value to the URL of the frame every time to bust the cache.

For example:

```html
<iframe src="page.asp?cachebuster=<%=(Timer() * 100)%>"></iframe>
```

Comment: please see the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304360/iframe-reload-caching-issue