# iframe reload caching issue

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am executing the following code in an iFrame:

```
window.frames[0].location.reload();
```

It reloads the page, however, it looks like **SOMETIMES** the data is cached.  I found the source of the URL that it is reloading.  What I would like to do is append a random number to the URL so that when it reloads it is unique and will prevent caching.

How would I do that with the above code?

**UPDATE:**

I have modified the code where I'm attempting to set the href to a new URL string that I built.  However, it looks like when I print out the location.href after setting it (the line above), I'm still getting the old location.href.

```
            window.frames[0].location.href = newIfURL;
            console.log(window.frames[0].location.href);
            window.frames[0].location.href();
```

Am I doing this right?

Comment: You should set the iframe `src` attribute, not its location.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - so should it be window.frames[0].src = newIfURL

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Ok - ultimately I want to reload the page with the new src - what do I call after I set the .src attribute?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - I tried setting the .src equal to the new URL and it did not behave the way I wanted to at all.  The page only loaded some of the elements (bad caching or something).  When I set the new url to the location.href I get the right page 80% of the time.  Setting the .src I got it right 0%...  I'm open to any and all suggestions.

Comment: What is `newIfURL`? What is its value?

Comment: href isn't a function so don't do `href()`.  When a location.href is set it should reload automatically, although I'm not sure if iframe location works the same as window/document location, but I think it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
var fl = window.frames[0].location;
var href = fl.protocol + '//' + fl.host + fl.pathname + '?random=' + Math.random() + fl.hash;
window.frames[0].location.href = href;
```

Of course, if you need to preserve "search" parameters, then you will need to add some logic to determine how to add the `random` parameter.

Comment: please see the updated question.  I used some of what you showed above but I'm still having some issues.  Any ideas?